# vhost set up help -- domain and ip point to the same site

Tags: virtualhost

I have these virtual hosts set up however when I browse to `domain.com` or `123.45.67.89` they both point to `/var/www/html/`. How can I get them set up so they point to correct DocumentRoot?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 123.45.67.89
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**: I actually had a seperate vhosts.conf file located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`. Subsequently this was being loaded (unbeknownst to me) by `Include conf.d/*.conf` before --

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

I have moved the vhosts out of that directory and into `/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/` and amended my Include file at the bottom of `httpd.conf` to --

```
Include /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

I have also tried uncommenting `ServerName` and defining it as my servers IP and removing the first `VirtualHost`.

The result of this is that `domain.com` points to the correct site though the IP points to that site now too.

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure these are in your Apache configuration BEFORE the `VirtualHost` containers:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

The reason you see the same content on both URLs is because Apache uses the FIRST `VirtualHost` as the "default" so any hostname not matching a `VirtualHost` will automatically be served as the first one you have.

Please report back the results.

Comment: I have that config already: `Listen 80` `NameVirtualHost *:80` `Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf`

Comment: @allanb - Would you mind posting your entire config? (Paste it somewhere).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z6Hetmzv

Comment: @allanb - I can't find anything technically wrong with your configuration. Though I probably missed something simple because it's very early in the morning and there are no lights in here, but maybe someone else could be of more help.